# Python > Uncompyle2 - usage

Tags: python

I'm trying to decompile some .pyc files - just need some basic data from them, I heard that best for it would be Uncompyle2,

so I installed Python27(Win), then I installed Uncompyle2 from https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2 - everything is ok so far, now I try to find out how to use it, readme says that I need to write `uncompyle2 --h` to get some more help, I'm getting after this "undefined" message, next I tried to import script via `import uncompyle2` in interpreter, I think module is loaded(after I type `uncompyle2` in interpreter it says, that it loaded functions from `__init__`) but still can't get any of it's functions to get work, if I try to do anything it says "syntax error"(even if I type everything just like from readme) and `--h` doesn't work either,

What I am doing wrong?

By the way, I tried to find some online converters, but since int's 2.6.4 python compiled files I can't find anything, that can work with it.

Comment: You're supposed to type `uncompyle2 --h` in your terminal, not in the Python interpreter. For Windows, you might need to edit the `PATH` variable (google it) to include the folder where uncompyle2 is installed.

Answer (score 13):

from IDLE

```
import uncompyle2
with open("uncompiled file.py", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file("afile.pyc", fileobj)
```

The result should be your uncompiled source code.

**EDIT 2/15/18**

for python 3 use [uncompyle 6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6) and open the output file in "w" mode (not "wb")

```
import uncompyle6
with open("uncompiled file.py", "w") as fileobj:
    uncompyle6.uncompyle_file("afile.pyc", fileobj)
```

Comment: You are a life saver :)

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` on uncompyle6 for python 3

Answer (score 2):

To run from your command line (PowerShell for example) you need to run the script uncompyle2 in Scripts, probably in C:\Python\Scripts if you installed Python to C:\Python. This will decompile the file somefile.pyc and create the file decompiled.py in c:\temp

PS C:\Python\Scripts> python .\uncompyle2 -o c:\temp\decompiled.py somefile.pyc

Answer (score 1):

I would just add to the accepted answer to do it all from the same directory, I got an empty `uncompiled file.py` folder when trying to run it from elsewhere. The whole script

```
import os

#this should be /folder_where_py_filtes_were/__pycache__/ in python3
os.chdir("C:\Dir where my pyc is")
import uncompyle2
with open("uncompiled file.py", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file("afile.pyc", fileobj)
```

Other than that you the man user2682863! saved my project

Comment: Yep, just make sure you uncompyle from /__pycache__/

Comment: LMK how that goes, I havent actually tested it in 3

Answer (score 1):

Just retried the version at https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

But it wasn't getting imported. I had to search the library and found that it had been renamed... so this is the code that has worked for me:

```
import uncompyle6
with open("uncompiled file.py", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle6.uncompyle_file("yourpycfile.pyc", fileobj)
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' on uncompyle6 for python 3